# Audio streaming from iPhone to a server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, network-programming, audio-streaming, audio-recording

How do I stream live audio recording from iPhone to a server? Do I really have to use RTP? 
Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I look at the following projects:

- http://www.iphone-recorder.com/about.html
- http://blog.pjsip.org/2009/02/19/native-iphone-sip-client-based-on-pjsip-available-on-app-store-open-source-and-not-tied-to-any-provider/
- http://code.google.com/p/siphon/

It seems to be possible that audio can be streamed. Am I missing something?